# Why do these printf statements cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c

When I run the following code, I get an error.

```
void printData(int total_trees,int burned){
  printf("Before printing data\n");
  float percentBurned = (float)burned / (total_trees+burned)*100;
  
  printf("total burned: %d (%.1f\%)\n",burned,percentBurned);
  printf("trees left: %d\n", total_trees);
  // printf("trees left: %d\n", total_trees);
  printf("After printing data");
}
```

The error says `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated`

Before outputting the error, it outputs the first three printf statements.

[Link to image because this is my first stackoverflow post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPQCh.png)

I've tried rearranging everything so many times and nothing has worked so far. I'm guessing the printf statements themselves aren't triggering an overflow, but I could be wrong.

I'm grateful for any help you can give :)

edit: `printf("trees left: %d\n", total_trees);` is the last line that runs before throwing the error

Comment: Does the error go away if you replace `\%` with `%%`?

Comment: Stack smashing is not the same as Stack Overflow. Overflow is making a call that requires more stack than is available. Stack smashing is detected writing outside already allocated space.

Comment: What makes you think that the line you specified is the last line that runs before the error is thrown? Did you come to this conclusion because `"trees left:"` is printed, but `"After printing data"` is not printed? Or did you run the program line by line in a debugger? If it is the former, then your conclusion could be false, because `stdout` is normally buffered and therefore not necessarily printed immediately. In that case, you may want to consider printing to `stderr` instead, which is normally unbuffered.

Comment: Gwendolyn Krezel, Curious why use `float percentBurned` and not `double percentBurned`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to escape a `%` character in a format string is `%%`, not `\%`.  A decent compiler should warn you about this if you enable warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall`), which you should always always do.

With that fixed, the program runs correctly for me, with all warnings and sanitizers that I tried [(try on godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/rTq43j8Yz).  If it still fails for you, then you need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as the bug may be in some other part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I figured out eventually that there is nothing wrong with this and there is something else in my code that is just bamboozling me, so I guess i'll figure it out.

Comment: `valgrind` may help